# (How) Can I retrieve a reference in a recursive function?

Tags: rust

I built a struct for a binary tree to which I want to add the `smallest` method.
The smallest element is always the last element found in left subtree recursion, so that is what I'm trying to implement.
However, I cannot return a temporary value from a method, so I get an error.

The obvious question now is how to rewrite my code in such a way that Rust and I are both happy.

I currently have this code in place.

```rust
pub struct Node<T: PartialOrd> {
    key: T,
    par_right: Option<bool>,
    parent: Option<Box<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    left_child: Option<Box<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    right_child: Option<Box<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T: PartialOrd> Node<T> {
    pub fn smallest(&self) -> &Self {
        match self.left_child.borrow() {
            Some(lc) => (**lc).borrow().smallest(),    // Error, return temporary
            None => self,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to make a self answer question "why people should stop do linked list to try to learn Rust". [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Comment: Look up how `RefCell` works - it guarantees safety by granting access through a lock guard (`Ref`) which unlocks the `RefCell` when dropped. That means if `smallest` has to recurse and call `.borrow()` 12 times, it must hold a stack of 12 nested `Ref` guards (the first one granting access to the second `RefCell`, etc.) What happens to those `Ref`s when `smallest` tries to return a reference to the inside of the innermost one?

Comment: @trentcl I would expect that the innermost recursive call drops the 'last' `Ref` value when it ends, invalidating the reference, but smart pointers are still very new to me. I could be wrong. Do you have any suggestions for a solution, perhaps? Or maybe an answer to your own question? I'd love to understand this better.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what happens. There's not just one solution. You could remove the `RefCell`, since without it you don't have to worry about guards. You might use `Rc` instead of `Box`. You could use raw pointers and `unsafe`. The site Stargateur linked describes all these and more in the context of linked lists (which are really just unary trees); I recommend reading through it before attempting any recursive data structures in Rust.

Comment: Wonderful tip @trentcl, thank you! I may indeed have jumped in the deep end a little too early. How about I read the chapters 18-20 of "The Book" first and look at Stargateur's link next, haha. Awesome support